# charAt is not a function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a key mapping that keeps track of the frequency for each character of a string in my createArrayMap() function but I keep getting this error from firebug: `TypeError: str.charAt(...) is not a function`

I found the charAt() function on Mozilla's developer website it should be a function that exists.

```
var input;
var container;
var str;
var arrMapKey = [];
var arrMapValue = [];


function initDocElements() {

    container = document.getElementById("container");
    input = document.getElementById("inputbox");

}

function createArrayMap() {
    str = input.value;
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (arrMapKey.find(str.charAt(i)) == undefined) {
            arrMapKey.push(str.charAt(i));
            arrMapValue.push(1);
        }
    }
}

function keyPressHandler() {
    createArrayMap();
    console.log(arrMapKey);
    console.log(arrMapValue);
}

function prepareEventHandlers() {
    input.onfocus = function() {
        if (this.value == "Start typing here!") {
            this.value = "";
        }
    };
    input.onblur = function() {
        if (this.value == "") {
            this.value = "Start typing here!";
        }
    };
    input.onkeyup = keyPressHandler;
}

window.onload = function() {
    initDocElements();
    prepareEventHandlers();
};
```

Comment: Can you share a link to a fiddle that has this problem?

Comment: Why not just use an object? `{a: 1, b: 2, ...}`

Comment: I don't see any reason to be using `charAt` in JavaScript. `"abc"[0]` is exactly the same as `"abc".charAt(0)` (Since a String is an Array you can do it that way.)

Comment: `arrMapKey.find` Array instance don't have such method. Are you using some kind of libraries? or extend array and string prototype yourself?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 - because `charAt()` has even better support than accessing strings with bracket notation, and is supported in all browsers, of course, it has to be a string for it to work

Comment: this is what I'm using as a reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference
@Givi I'm not using any libraries

Comment: Just a sidenote to your "Start typing here", if you're not plan on supporting IE9, you could use the placeholder attribute instead: http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder

Comment: I'm actually curious as to what the `Array.find` method is doing, and where you found it (you're sure it should'nt be indexOf) ?

Comment: @Tharabas thanks that works a lot better

Comment: @adeneo here's the link where I found it:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: @Blender But wouldn't I have to define a key value myself for every single character there is? I just want to make a key for each character in the string

Comment: Whenever you see a notice that says "Experimental - ES6 harmony", it's probably not a good idea to use it, as most browsers won't support it.

Comment: @user2852358: Then just check beforehand: `if (!(key in obj)) { obj[key] = 1; } else { obj[key]++; }`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not with [`String.charAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt), but with [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

The first argument to `find` is a callback, but the result of `str.charAt(i)` is a character and not a callback function.

To search for an element in your array, you could use [`Array.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) as @adeneo already suggested in a comment

```js
function createArrayMap() {
    var str = input.value;
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (arrMapKey.indexOf(str.charAt(i)) == -1) {
            arrMapKey.push(str.charAt(i));
            arrMapValue.push(1);
        }
    }
}
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xaK3E/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You're not going about things in the most efficient manner... What if you changed it to look like this so you are continually updated with each keypress?

```
var keyMap = {};
...
input.onkeyup = keyPressHandler;

function keyPressHandler(e) {
  var char = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
  if(!(char in keyMap))
    keyMap[char] = 1;
  else
    keyMap[char]++;
}
```

Comment: Any reason for the downvote... this is a much simpler algorithm and more efficient.

Comment: `typeof(keyMap[char]) != 'undefined'` can just be `!(char in keymap)`. Otherwise, +1, this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered, but here's my version of your problem [JSBIN LINK](http://jsbin.com/oSIZEMuR/2/edit?html,js,output) (also has an object option in addition to the array solution).

I moved some variables around so you'll have less global ones, added comments, and mocked with the output so it'll show it on the page instead of the console.

besides the `Array.find()` issues, you weren't initializing your arrays on the build method, and so, you would have probably ended with the wrong count of letters.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<textArea id="inputbox"></textArea></div>
<p id="output">output will show here</p>
```

JS:

```
var input,      // Global variables
    container,  //
    output;     //

/**
 * Initialize components
 */
function initDocElements() {
    container = document.getElementById("container");
    input = document.getElementById("inputbox");
    output = document.getElementById("output");
}

/**
 * Creates the letters frequency arrays.
 * Note that every time you click a letter, this is done from scratch.
 * Good side: no need to deal with "backspace"
 * Bad side: efficiency. Didn't try this with huge texts, but you get the point ...
 */
function createArrayMap() {
    var index,                  // obvious
        tempChar,               // temp vars for: char 
        tempStr = input.value,  // string
        len = tempStr.length,   // for loop iteration
        arrMapKey   = [],       // our keys
        arrMapValue = [];       // our values

    for (var i = 0 ; i <len ; i++) {

        // These 2 change each iteration
        tempChar = tempStr.charAt(i);
        index = arrMapKey.indexOf(tempChar); 

        // If key exists, increment value
        if ( index > -1) {          
            arrMapValue[index]++;
        }   
        // Otherwise, push to keys array, and push 1 to value array
        else {                      
            arrMapKey.push(tempChar);
            arrMapValue.push(1);
        }
    }

    // Some temp output added, instead of cluttering the console, to the 
    // a paragraph beneath the text area.
    output.innerHTML = "array keys:   "+arrMapKey.toString() + 
        "<br/>array values:"+arrMapValue.toString();
}

function keyPressHandler() {
    createArrayMap();

}

function prepareEventHandlers() {
    input.onfocus = function() {
        if (this.value == "Start typing here!") {
            this.value = "";
        }
    };
    input.onblur = function() {
        if (this.value === "") {
            this.value = "Start typing here!";
        }
    };
    input.onkeyup = keyPressHandler;
}

window.onload = function() {
    initDocElements();
    prepareEventHandlers();
};
```

BTW, as the comments suggest, doing this with an object will is much nicer and shorter, since all you care is if the object has the current char as a property:

```
/**
 * Same as above method, using an object, instead of 2 arrays
 */
function createObject() {
    var index,                  // obvious
        tempChar,               // temp vars for: char 
        tempStr = input.value,  // string
        len = tempStr.length,   // for loop iteration
        freqObj = {};           // our frequency object

    for (var i = 0 ; i <len ; i++) {
        tempChar = tempStr.charAt(i);   // temp char value

        if (freqObj.hasOwnProperty(tempChar))
            freqObj[tempChar]++;
        else
            freqObj[tempChar] = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! using an object is much nicer didn't realize you could check if a property exists like that @Blender